# MySQL SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY 'which one has the latest record in other table '

Tags: html, mysql, sql, web

I have the following tables:

```
chats:
+--------+-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
| chatID | firstPerson | secondPerson | chatAccepted | creationDate        |
+--------+-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 1      | 59          | 52           | 1            | 31-01-2014 09:32:37 |
| 2      | 59          | 12           | 0            | 28-01-2014 11:07:25 |
| 3      | 34          | 59           | 1            | 28-01-2014 08:50:48 |
| 4      | 78          | 59           | 1            | 26-01-2014 03:58:12 |
+--------+-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+

messages:
+-----------+-------------+--------+----------+------------+---------------------+
| messageID | messageText | chatID | senderID | receiverID | creationDate        |
+-----------+-------------+--------+----------+------------+---------------------+
| 1         | Lorum...    | 1      | 59       | 52         | 31-01-2014 09:32:37 |
| 2         | Ipsum...    | 1      | 52       | 59         | 28-01-2014 11:07:25 |
| 3         | Dollar...   | 3      | 34       | 59         | 28-01-2014 08:50:48 |
| 4         | Sit...      | 3      | 59       | 34         | 31-01-2014 11:09:48 |
+-----------+-------------+--------+----------+------------+---------------------+
```

What I'm trying to get as a result is the chatID where (firstPerson = 59 or secondPerson = 59) and chatAccepted = 1. Now the thing I can't get figured out: I want the result ordered by 'which one has the latest message'.

I tried a lot of different things, one was:

```
"SELECT chats.chatID, chats.firstPerson, chats.secondPerson, str_to_date(messages.creationDate,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS cdate
    FROM chats
    INNER JOIN messages
    ON chats.chatID=messages.chatID 
    WHERE chats.chatAccepted = 1 AND messages.receiverID = 59
    UNION SELECT chats.chatID, chats.firstPerson, chats.secondPerson, str_to_date(messages.creationDate,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS cdate
    FROM chats
    INNER JOIN messages
    ON chats.chatID=messages.chatsID 
    WHERE chats.chatAccepted = 1 AND messages.senderID = 59
    ORDER BY cdate desc"
```

This works like a charm, except for when there are no messages yet. Than it just results no records. But i need to know if that chat is accepted otherwise they can never even start the chat.

Any help would be very welcome.
If you need any more information please led me know!

UPDATE: so what I at least want as a result in this case would be:

```
+--------+
| chatID |
+--------+
| 3      |
| 1      |
| 4      |
+--------+
```

this because chatID '3' has the latest message linked to it. chatID '4' has no messages yet, but it is a accepted chat so it should be in the result.

Comment: What would the desired result actually look like?

Comment: your totla operation is very much costly to find latest message

Comment: Also, wouldn't a message be available to all participants of a 'chat'?

Comment: I don't see why this is a bad question so why the -1? Anyway @ Strawberry a chat is between 2 persons and is only displayed if both persons accepted it to chat with each other.

Comment: My point is, if a chat only exists between two persons, and we know who the message sender is, the message receiver is redundant.

Comment: That's true, but we don't. We only know that the sender id '59' OR the receiver is '59'. That also isn't the problem I'm facing. The problem is within the order. I just want to get the chatID's that satisfy the mentioned demands and on top of that I want them ordered in the way that the one which has the latest message linked to it comes out on top.

Comment: OT, but how long did it take you to draw these tables? Or did you use some kind of a trick to create them?

Comment: I'm sorry strawberry, you're right. the union select can be skipped since I already know the chatID belongs to that person.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  c.chatID, c.firstPerson, c.secondPerson, str_to_date(m.creationDate,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS cdate
FROM    chats c left join messages m on c.chatID=m.chatID 
WHERE   c.chatAccepted = 1 AND 
        59 in (m.senderID, m.receiverID)
ORDER BY m.creationDate desc
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, this looks light weighted and convincing. But I get the error: #1054 - Unknown column 'chats.chatID' in 'on clause'

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to think.. after I changed chats in c and messages in d, it worked. but I get no results. So something is wrong, however can't find what .

Comment: I get a result now I removed '59 in...' but now the cdate is null, probably because it gets more than 1 creationDate since there are more messages per chat. I'm sure that the str_to_date(m.creationDate,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To keep also chats whit no messages you need a `LEFT JOIN` then you should decide witch order have the chats without messages, suppose you want use the chat creation date, then use the `COALESCE` function to select chat creation date where there are no messages (message creation date is NULL).

In this way you have multiple entry for chats with more messages, than you have to use also the aggregation funcion `MAX` on cDate to have only last messages entries:

```
SELECT c.chatID,
       c.firstPerson,
       c.secondPerson,
       str_to_date(MAX(COALESCE(m.creationDate, c.creationDate)),'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS cdate
  FROM chats AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       messages AS m ON c.ChatID = m.ChatID
 WHERE c.Accepted = 1 AND (c.firstPerson=59 OR c.SecondPerson=59)
 GROUP BY c.chatID, c.firstPerson, c.secondPerson
 ORDER BY cdate DESC
```

I'm not sure if in MySql applying the str_to_date function to an aggregate field works, in the negative case the query should be rewritten as:

```
SELECT chatID,
       firstPerson,
       secondPerson,
       str_to_date(cdate,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS cdate
  FROM (SELECT c.chatID,
               c.firstPerson,
               c.secondPerson,
               MAX(COALESCE(m.creationDate, c.creationDate)) AS cdate
          FROM chats AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN 
               messages AS m ON c.ChatID = m.ChatID
         WHERE c.Accepted = 1 AND (c.firstPerson=59 OR c.SecondPerson=59)
         GROUP BY c.chatID, c.firstPerson, c.secondPerson
         ORDER BY cdate DESC) AS devTbl
```

I hope this help